# Attempt to call function 'get_position' in base 'null instance' on a null instance. ERROR

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am trying to create a topdown shooter with a player and a bullet on a separate scene. But whenever I run the game it says

> Attempt to call function 'get_position' in base 'null instance' on a null instance.

BTW I am new to Godot.
The problem seems to be in this function:

```
const SPEED = 300
var bullet = preload("res://Mini-Scenes/Bullet.tscn")

func shoot():
    var b = bullet.instance()
    add_child(b)
    b.set_position(position)
    b.move_and_slide(Vector2(1, 0).rotated(rotation) * SPEED)
```

And I also don't think that I understand how instancing works,
so my questions are:

1. How does *Instancing* work?
2. What makes the above function fail?

Comment: I'm also new and had a similar problem recently, I tried creating player and main scene together, and I think you can not use the get_position function if the parent node is a Node2D (like usually the map one). Can you try to move your shoot function to the bullet or player scene?

Comment: `Attempt to call function 'get_position' in base 'null instance' on a null instance` means the enginge can't find what you're requesting. Try changing your `var bullet` to `onready var bullet`. If it still doesn't work, try changing `b.set_position(position)` to `b.position = position`.

Comment: I changed the Node2D to Node, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I forgot to mention... if none of my above suggestions work, try adding the bullet with `get_parent().add_child(b)`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, in order:

1. Instancing is simple in principle. Godot takes the base `Node` of a scene and all its children, and copy-and-pastes them into memory. Then, when you add this `Node` as child to another in the scene, `_ready` is called, the `Node`s begin to `_process` and `_physics_process`, as well as a few other things like receive events (as a `Node` must be within a `SceneTree` in order to interact with other nodes, and the most common way to add one to a tree is making it the child of another).

For more information, see the [documentation on Instancing](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/step_by_step/instancing.html)

2. The above function actually works flawlessly, I just created a new project in Godot 3.1.1 and duplicated your setup, no errors occur. The problem must be somewhere else in your code or your scene setup, and we'd need to see your full script and scene layout to determine the cause of the problem. If you update your question with that information, or shoot me a message on Discord (Mantissa#2558), I'll be able to fully answer your question.